# Is it possible with Estimote or native code to have in the same app many regions and assign 1 or many beacons to each region?

Tags: android, ios, ibeacon, estimote

Is it possible with Estimote or native code to have in the same app many regions and assign 1 or many beacons to each region?

I want to send different notification messages when a user is aproaching to certain beacons and I will have many beacons in the same place.

Comment: don't include your title as the first sentence in your question. that wastes peoples reading time, and has no benefit. maybe use a much shorter title.

Answer (score 0):

A great overview of iBeacons/BLE beacons is the Getting Started with iBeacon downloadable PDF on [Apple's iBeacon for Developers page](https://developer.apple.com/ibeacon/). As you can see that doc, each beacon has has three identifiers that they broadcast for phones to pick up: A *UUID*, a *Major* (another ID that is commonly referred to as a "sub-region"), and a *Minor*. The UUID is is usually referred to as the "Region", the Major and Minor are additional identifiers to further divide up the beacons within a region. Using [startMonitoringForRegion](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/CLLocationManager/startMonitoringForRegion:), an app can register up to 20 regions at a time.

There are good examples in there to further understand how to best use these identifiers, but generally your app declares a Region/UUID it wants to listen for and it will be woken up when one is detected. This can be done in a power-efficient way on iOS. Once your app is woken up, it will use the Major to determine which "subregion" it is nearest to and the Minor to determine which beacon it is nearest to within the "subregion".

### Waking the app

In iOS, using [startMonitoringForRegion](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/CLLocationManager/startMonitoringForRegion:) if a region boundary crossing occurs while your iOS app is not running, the system automatically wakes it up (or relaunches it) in the background so that it can process the event. See the *Using Location Services in the Background* section of the [CLLocationManager Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/index.html) for more information. Note, you'll only get a notification though, the app doesn't necessarily coe to the foreground. Generally what you would want to do is launch a notification to the user encouraging them to bring the app to the foreground. A good video on notifications, including how to trigger notifications using geofences and iBeacons, is the [*What's New in iOS Notifications* video from WWDC2014](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2014/?id=713).

Comment: do you know how to awake the app? I'm new in objective C

Comment: @AlbertoFuentes I added more info to my answer above about awaking the app based on your comment. If this answer answers your question please [accept the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be notified when enter/exit region occur, on iOS, CoreLocation limits you to monitoring for **at most 20 different UUIDs**.

I believe you want to get the advantage of IOS to wake up your app when enter/exit region occurs. That is why you want to use different regions. After your app is waken up by IOS, you can send notifications as you wish. If you can fit into 20 region limit you can achieve this by using different UUIDs for different groups of iBeacons.